# Create Topic in Foswiki server based on JSON input from external system

Tags: wiki, foswiki

I want to create a topic on foswiki instance running on web server on local machine based on data coming from external system. The new topic data will be sent via POST request from external system (client) to this local machine's (server URL) port XXXX. When the data arrives at the port XXXX some how a new topic or update topic (if exist) event should be triggered on foswiki local instance. How can I achieve this? (any programming language)

The client and server machines are on LAN.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at WebDAVContrib. It has got a json view for topics. So you might simply upload a MyNewTopic.json to a webdav drive and the topic will be created accordingly.

Comment: I installed WebDAVContrib plugin and resolved the cpan dependencies. Now what's the next step? Do I have to configure with Apache mod_perl, FastCGI or HTTP::Daemon? Can you please tell how to link client browser to foswiki web server? Sorry, I am newbie to foswiki.